# How to get field name of item in sitecore when creating custom event handlers

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6

In the handler I need to get a fields names(not field values!) that have been modified and add them to the log. I've tried `item.DisplayName`, `item.Name`, but it's a value of the field, not a name.

```
public void OnItemSavedHandled(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  Item temp = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
  Log.Info(string.Format(
           "Item field {0} was modified at: {1}, by user:{2}",
           temp.DisplayName,
           DateTime.Now.ToString(), Sitecore.Context.User.Name),
           this);
}
```

This code add to log a value, not a name of the field. How to get a name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to use the event handlers, you should consider using the `OnItemSaving` event instead of the `OnItemSaved` event. Before an item is saved, you can loop through it's fields to determine if a field value has changed using the `Field.IsFieldModified` property of an individual field. Otherwise, if you use the `OnItemSaved` handler, you'll have to retrieve the `ItemChanges` object for the item that was saved, loop through fields in the `ItemChanges`, and check the `IsFieldModified` property there.

Here is code for the OnItemSaving event handler:

```
public void OnItemSaving(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Item item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
    if (item == null)
        return;

    item.Fields.ReadAll(); 
    foreach (Field field in item.Fields)
    {
        if (!field.IsModified) //check if the field is modified
            continue;

        Log.Audit(string.Format("OnItemSaving - Item field {0} was modified at: {1}, by user: {2}", field.DisplayName, item.Statistics.Updated.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), item.Statistics.UpdatedBy), this);
    }
}
```

With all of that said, I wouldn't actually recommend using the `OnItemSaved` or `OnItemSaving` events for your purposes. The saved/saving events are raised by the API as a part of ANY save operation performed on the item - whether by Sitecore or by a Sitecore user. Therefore, you may notice that the events are being raised when you wouldn't normally expect them to be. For instance, during the publish process, a save operation is executed and therefore the saved/saving events are raised. There may be other instances when unintended save operations occur as well.

It sounds like you'd rather just capture user save events? i.e. when a content author clicks the 'Save' button for a specific item? If so, I would recommend tapping into the `Sitecore.Pipelines.Save` pipeline. This pipeline is triggered only when a Sitecore UI save event occurs (e.g. Save button click, Ctrl+S hot key save, etc...)

To use the `Sitecore.Pipelines.Save` pipeline, you will need to create a processor for the pipeline, then add it to the `/sitecore/process/saveUI` processor in your web.config file (ideally, via a config include file). Here is code you could use for the pipeline processor:

```
public class LogFieldChanges
{
    public void Process(SaveArgs args)
    {
        foreach (var saveItem in args.Items) //loop through item(s) being saved
        {
            var item = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(saveItem.ID, saveItem.Language, saveItem.Version); //get the actual item being saved
            if (item == null)
                continue;

            foreach (var saveField in saveItem.Fields) //loop through the fields being saved
            {
                var field = item.Fields[saveField.ID]; //retrieve the Field from the actual item
                var isModified = saveField.OriginalValue != saveField.Value; //determine if the field has been modified, we only want to log modified fields
                if (field == null || !isModified)
                    continue;

                Log.Audit(string.Format("SaveUI - Item field {0} was modified at: {1}, by user: {2}", field.DisplayName, item.Statistics.Updated.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), item.Statistics.UpdatedBy), this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order for this code to work, it's important that your custom processor be inserted AFTER the `Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Save` processor. By placing it after that processor, you're able to use the `SaveField.OriginalValue` and `SaveField.Value` properties to determine if the field has been modified. Also, by placing your processor after the `Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Save` processor, you're able to use the `Item.Statistics` properties to determine when and by whom the item was saved.

```
<sitecore>
    <processors>
        <saveUI>            
            .
            .
            <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Save, Sitecore.Kernel" />
            <!-- insert your processor after the Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Save processor -->
            <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Extensions.Pipelines.Save.LogFieldChanges, Sitecore.Extensions"/>
            .
            .
         </saveUI>
    </processors>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Only remark: use include files rather than changing the web.config: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-Web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

Comment: I am using Sitecore 7 and the properties for the field are not the same, in particular: field.DisplayName.

Comment: @Adam Weber: In the line: foreach (var saveField in saveItem.Fields) it is better to put File as the type, rather than var, in order to get all the properties for the object.

Comment: @DanielV, DisplayName is a property of the "Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field" type, which is the type of the "field" variable. Are you referring to the "saveField" variable? That variable is of type "Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.SaveArgs.SaveField", which does not have a DisplayName property. I would not recommend casting "saveField" to type "File" - I don't think that's even a valid cast. Perhaps you meant to cast the "field" variable to type "FIle"? Even so, that isn't recommended either unless you know that the field you're processing is actually a "File" field.

Answer (score 3):

When you save an item minimun 4 fields I guess are save: item you modify,_*Updated by,*_Updated and Revision fields
 The solution is next one

```
    public void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        SitecoreEventArgs eventArgs = args as SitecoreEventArgs;
        Debug.Assert(eventArgs != null, "eventArgs != null");
        //get the item who was changed
        Item item = eventArgs.Parameters[0] as Item;
        //get the fields that was modified
        ItemChanges list = eventArgs.Parameters[1] as ItemChanges;

        //parse the list of items and check if current field was modified
        // I didn't find an solution without parsing list
        foreach (Field field in list.Item.Fields)
            if (list.IsFieldModified(field))
            {
                //get the field Name
                string s = field.Name;
            }
        //now your code
    }
```

Comment: You parse all the item fields and check if was modified. Personal I don't like solution, but I didn't find other solution but I didn't search to much time for it...

Comment: @User answering regarding what is '`Field` field' -> *`Item` is an collection of many Fields* and `Field` is an type of class same as we have `Item`. You will find more details at [Sitecore SDN regarding Field Types](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Media/Referencing%20Binary%20Items/Field%20Types.aspx)

Comment: [API Doc link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/doc/api%205.1.1/Sitecore.Data.Fields.html) Regarding Field class in Sitecore SDN